# Obtain the boundaries from a png file

Tags: r, r-sp

I am wondering how to obtain the boundaries from this kind of image.

For example:

[image]

I was looking converting some image using

```
image <- as(x, 'SpatialGridDataFrame')
```

But it only give me special heavy images.

In this case, using this x_coord and y_coord I am be able to create a simple object.

```
 x_coord <- c(16.48438,  17.49512,  24.74609, 22.59277, 16.48438)
 y_coord <- c(59.736328125, 55.1220703125, 55.0341796875, 
 61.142578125, 59.736328125)
 xym <- cbind(x_coord, y_coord)
 xym

 library(sp)
 p = Polygon(xym)
 ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
 sps1 = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
 plot(sps1)
```

I expect to obtain a set of x_coord and y_coord for the circle png added as example.

Comment: How did you read your image file?

Comment: `library(imager)`
`im <- load.image("circle.jpg")`
`plot(im)` @TeeKea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pixsets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imager/vignettes/pixsets.html) approach (in the **imager** package) to identify the edges of the circle in the given image, as follows:

```
px <- im > 0.6 #Select pixels of the circle (i.e., those with high luminance)
plot(px)
```

Now, when you plot `px`, you get the following:

[image: pixels]

To get the coordinates of the pixels, you use the following:

```
coord <- where(px)
head(coord)
```

which gives you something like this:

```
#  x y cc
#1 1 1  1
#2 2 1  1
#3 3 1  1
#4 4 1  1
#5 5 1  1
#6 6 1  1
```

To get the boundaries, you use the following:

```
boundaries <- boundary(px)
boundaries.xy <- where(boundaries)
head(boundaries.xy)
```

which gives you the following:

```
#    x  y cc
#1 103 64  1
#2 102 65  1
#3 104 65  1
#4 103 66  1
#5 185 71  1
#6 184 72  1
```

You may even save the circle pixels as follows:

```
px_image <- as.cimg(px)
save.image(px_image, "px_image.jpg")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem of finding the boundaries.